# Simple (?) MySQL Group by query

Tags: mysql

My code

```
select 
    (select ifnull(sum(registerAmount),0) 
     from register where register.orderID = orders.orderID) as theTotal 
from orders 
left join register on orders.orderID = register.orderID 
where orders.customerID = 17 and invSent = true
```

Displays 8 rows... 5 contain zero and 3 do not.

If I add

```
group by orders.customerID
```

I get one row that contains zero.

How do I get one row that contains the total?

Comment: left OUTER join perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one row with the total of everything, just do a simple INNER JOIN and select the sum.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(registerAmount), 0) as theTotal
FROM orders
INNER JOIN register ON orders.orderID = register.orderID
WHERE orders.customerID = 17 and invSent = true
```

Comment: This is actually part of a bigger query that I am trying to debug.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a mind reader, I can't make my answer fit into the larger context if I don't know what it is.

Comment: You should be able to use this answer as a subquery within your larger query, and join with it.